# Xcode 5.1 call stack in debug , show only thread without any info about the functions in c++

Tags: c++, xcode5

i try to debug c++ code in xcode 5.1, in some point i have exception which in visual studio   2012 i used to get massage that tell me to break and then i see call stack ,
but this is not the case in xcode i get the same exception but i can't see the function flow aka the call   stack . 
here is what i see in xcode :

[image: xcode call stack]

Answer (score 3):

In the left panel go down to the bottom and move the slider to the right to expand the entire call stack.

Comment: I think they collapse it to show all of the threads and then you can zoom using the slider at the bottom to see more detailed information.

Comment: ok i found out its not covering all the exceptions , another way it is to add the exception breakpoint, ok i wrong not even the exception break point cover it , im stack with exception that i dont know from where it came ....):